# session value when compare with variable value then its showing they are not equal

Tags: scala, session, playframework

i am new at scala and play 2.1 and from php background ,in the below code the session userId and userId values are equal but else condition is executing, i dont understand why its happening.

```
@session.get("userId")                  //21 on webpage
@println(session.get("userId"))         //some(21) on console
@userId                                 //21 on webpage 
@println(userId)                        //21 on console
@println(session.get("userId").get)     //21 on console
@if((session.get("userId").get)==userId){
<input type="file" value="image" style="position:absolute;opacity:0.0;" name="image" style="70px;" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();">
}else{
<input type='button' value='Add' />
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the types of `userId` and `session.get("userId")`?

Comment: Most likely one of them is an `Int` while the other one is a `String`

Comment: yes, i get it.
session variable is of string type.

Comment: too simple question in scala..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a case of type mismatch. The values stored in session are of string type by default. And I think the values userId is of Int or long type. So convert your session value to same type, you are comparing with i.e. use session.get("userId").get.toInt to change in integer type and then compare it.